# Sort pandas DataFrame first by subject ID then pick their corresponding values from other columns

Tags: python, performance, pandas

```
NOTES=[]
hadm=[]
for i in sorted(list(notes_df.SUBJECT_ID.unique())):
    #print(i)
    NOTES.append(list(notes_df[notes_df.SUBJECT_ID == i].TEXT))
    hadm.append(list(notes_df[notes_df.SUBJECT_ID == i].HADM_ID.astype(float)))
notes_1_df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(sorted(list(notes_df.SUBJECT_ID.unique())),hadm,[item for sublist in NOTES for item in sublist])), columns =['SUBJECT_ID','HADM_ID','NOTES'])
notes_1_df.HADM_ID=notes_1_df.HADM_ID.astype(str)
```

The above code works fine to generate a new `Dataframe` with sorted values of subject ID and its corresponding values of other column. I used lists to store values and then used them to create a `Dataframe`.

But it is slow. How to make it fast?

`notes_df` structure:

```
ROW_ID|SUBJECT_ID|HADM_ID|TEXT
1      4           89     Here is the text
2      23          433    Here is the text,and so on
3      65          1212   Here is the text,and 
4      914         2212   Here is the text,and so on
5      23          112    Here is the text,and so on
6      23          773    Here is the text,and so on
7      65          1210   Here is the text,and so 
8      23          1212   Here is the text,and so on
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What makes your code slow is the repeated calls to `unique`, and manually shunting all entries into lists repeatedly. Ideally you want to do it all in `pandas` for the most speed.

If I understand it correctly, you want to group by the subject ID, collect all hadm IDs and texts. In that case, you can just use [`pandas.DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [`pandas.DataFrame.aggregate`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.aggregate.html) to achieve (almost) the same result:

```
notes_1_df = notes_df.drop(columns=["ROW_ID"]) \
                     .groupby("SUBJECT_ID") \
                     .aggregate(list) \
                     .reset_index()
```

Which directly produces this output:

```
   SUBJECT_ID                HADM_ID                                               TEXT
0           4                   [89]                                 [Here is the text]
1          23  [433, 112, 773, 1212]  [Here is the text,and so on, Here is the text,...
2          65           [1212, 1210]    [Here is the text,and, Here is the text,and so]
3         914                 [2212]                       [Here is the text,and so on]
```

Whereas your code produces:

```
   SUBJECT_ID                        HADM_ID                       NOTES
0           4                         [89.0]            Here is the text
1          23  [433.0, 112.0, 773.0, 1212.0]  Here is the text,and so on
2          65               [1212.0, 1210.0]  Here is the text,and so on
3         914                       [2212.0]  Here is the text,and so on
```

This differs mainly in the notes. Here your code is a bit weird. Instead of doing what you did, let's just pick the first text from each subject for now.

I am assuming that having integers for the hadm ID is fine, otherwise you can be more specific and supply two different functions to `aggregate`, in which case you don't even need the `drop` anymore:

```
notes_1_df = notes_df.groupby("SUBJECT_ID") \
                     .aggregate({"HADM_ID": lambda x: list(map(float, x)),
                                 "TEXT": "first"}) \
                     .rename(columns={"TEXT": "NOTES"}) \
                     .reset_index()
```

```
   SUBJECT_ID                        HADM_ID                       NOTES
0           4                         [89.0]            Here is the text
1          23  [433.0, 112.0, 773.0, 1212.0]  Here is the text,and so on
2          65               [1212.0, 1210.0]        Here is the text,and
3         914                       [2212.0]  Here is the text,and so on
```

---

To see why I think your code produces weird results, let's replace the text with unique texts:

```
df["TEXT"] = "Text from subject " + df.SUBJECT_ID.astype(str) + ", hadm " + df.HADM_ID.astype(str)
```

Then my (last) code produces:

```
   SUBJECT_ID                        HADM_ID                             NOTES
0           4                         [89.0]      Text from subject 4, hadm 89
1          23  [433.0, 112.0, 773.0, 1212.0]    Text from subject 23, hadm 433
2          65               [1212.0, 1210.0]   Text from subject 65, hadm 1212
3         914                       [2212.0]  Text from subject 914, hadm 2212
```

Where each text is the first text from that actual subject. In contrast, your code produces:

```
   SUBJECT_ID                        HADM_ID                           NOTES
0           4                         [89.0]    Text from subject 4, hadm 89
1          23  [433.0, 112.0, 773.0, 1212.0]  Text from subject 23, hadm 433
2          65               [1212.0, 1210.0]  Text from subject 23, hadm 112
3         914                       [2212.0]  Text from subject 23, hadm 773
```

Note how the texts do not correspond to the same subjects anymore!

Comment: what does `'TEXT':'first'` do? also on my side, My NOTES column collects all notes under same Subject_ID in a list ,Unlike what is specified in answer. I also didnt understand this "The first text (which is implicitly selected in your code by using zip, which clips at the end of the shortest iterable) can be selected using notes_1_df.TEXT.str[0] or using the first function"

Comment: @AdityaVartak: It applies the function [`first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html), which takes the first element in the group. It's a pandas specialty that you can pass a string instead of the function, it only works for some. Your code is a bit weird, you collect the notes per subject ID (as does my first code), but then you do `[item for sublist in NOTES for item in sublist]`, which means you loose the connection between the text and the subject/hadm ID.  Try it with unique texts for each row to see the difference.

Comment: yeah i just tried out your code on the data and i see the notes in the beginning are properly coming as expected. but the notes near the end are all jumbled

Comment: for `[item for sublist in NOTES for item in sublist]` I was trying to pick up a subnote list from list of notes then pick the note from the sublist as notes are inside lists which are collected together as a single list for single subject ID

Comment: @AdityaVartak: Added an example with more easily identified texts.

Comment: what if i want to collect all texts and not just the first. I mean that I want to make a list of list for all texts of that subject(similar to way it is done for hadm id) ,Order is not compulsorily important but better if it is.

Comment: @AdityaVartak: See my first code block, that is exactly what that code is doing.

Comment: Ok i get it now.So i should execute it in 2 steps first the above code then the below one?

Comment: @AdityaVartak: No, they are two slightly different ways. The first one just collates both hadm IDs and texts into lists each, per subject. The second one was me trying to more closely emulate the behavior of your code and discovering that your code is a bit weird :). They are completely independent.

Comment: okay so what shall i change in 2nd code to make sure i can collect list of lists of the note and in proper order as you talked about

Comment: @AdityaVartak Nothing, just use the first, adding the `rename` from the second.

Comment: I was asking regarding `'first'` arguement.I dont need only the 1st note, need all notes for subject ID. So should i delete the ` "TEXT": "first"` or any other way?

Comment: @AdityaVartak Again, just use the first code block. It puts both the hadm IDs and the texts in lists. The only real difference is in how I used the `aggreggate` method.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Graipher I am accepting the solution